# Are $C^{\infty}$ completely defined by their derivatives?

Tags: functions, derivatives

This question has been on my mind for some time. Here's my process.

Firstly, is it possible to construct a function such that it's defined with a different expression on different intervals, but that it's still in $C^{\infty}$?

For example, say we define a function like this:

$f(x)=\cos x$ for $x\ge0$

$f(x)=1 + \sin (x)$ for $x\le0$

The function is continuous. It's first derivative is

$f'(x)=-\sin x$ for $x\ge0$

$f'(x)=\cos x$ for $x\le0$

Not continuous.

If I chose two functions and match their values AND first derivatives, they differ in the third derivative. If I match that one also, the differ in the fourth... well, you get the point.

So I was thinking, could it be that a function in $C^{\infty}$ is fully defined by all it's derivatives in a single point? 
If I want to make a polynomial that aproximates the $\sin$ function, I can make it of an arbitrarily high degree and match as many derivatives as I want. Say I have a sequence of functions $g_n$, such that $g_n^{(i)}(x_0)=\sin^{(i)}(x_0)$ for every $i\in\{0,...,n\}$.

Is $\lim_n g_n=\sin$?

If not for every $g_n$, is it true if we restrict $g_n$s to polynomials of $n$th degree?

Comment: Check what happens at $0$ with $e^{-1/x^2}$ (defined as $0$ at $0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question "could it be that a function in $C^{\infty}$ is fully defined by all it's derivatives in a single point?", the answer is no. In fact, there does not exist *any* function $h(x) \in C^{\infty}$ that we can detect simply by knowing all the derivatives of the function at some point $a\in \mathbb{R}.$ This is because the smooth function $h(x) + f(x-a)$ (where f is as in Hagen's answer) has all the same derivatives at $a$ as $h(x).$

In fact, even the values of all the derivatives for all points in a huge interval $[-M, \infty)$ is not enough to decide between $h(x)$ or $h(x) + f(x+M)$ or $h(x) + \sin(x^3) f(x+M)$ ...

If you know about convolutions, then from $f$ you can explicitly construct a smooth function $\tilde{f}$ so that $$\tilde{f}(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\ge 0\\
e^{1/x}&\text{if } -\epsilon/2 < x<0 \\ g(x) &\text{if } -\epsilon< x \leq -\epsilon/2 \\ 0 & \text{if } x\leq \epsilon \end{cases}$$

where $g$ starts at $0$ and smoothly rises up until it connects with the $e^{1/x}$ component. Now we can conclude that its not even enough to know the values of all derivatives at all points on $\mathbb{R}$ excluding any tiny interval of length $\epsilon$ ! Even if you know all derivatives outside of $[a, a+\epsilon]$ you can't distinguish between $h(x)$ or $h(x) + (x^2\tan(e^x))\tilde{f}(x-a-\epsilon).$

Intuitively, the reason knowledge of derivatives at points fails to determine a unique function is because derivatives give *local* information (they only depend on, and hence give you information about) the behavior of the function in small neighborhoods of the points. To pin down a function, you need *global* information, knowledge about the function everywhere.

P.S. You'll be in for a treat when you study complex analysis!

Comment: Knowing that derivatives only give me local information I was hoping that higher derivatives had more "influence" on the rest of the function and, by extent, the infinityth derivative has ultimate influence. What about my other question? Will a polynomial of infinite degree that matches all the derivatives of $sin$ in a point perfectly approximate it?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty scared of complex analysis. Real analysis was very difficult to grasp and the tiny parts where we touched complex numbers seemed very confusing to me.

Answer (score 6):

Consider
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\ge 0\\
e^{1/x}&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$

All derivatives at $x=0$ are zero (from the left they look like polynomial in $\frac1x$ times exponential, and the exponential always wins). So we cannot conclude anything about $f$ from knowing only all $f^{(n)}(0)$ (in fact not even knowing $f|_{[0,\infty)}$  helps).
You may be interested in *analytic* functions, which are much more rigidly determined by local data.

Comment: This is a bit awkward since I haven't thought of it sooner, but when I was thinking about this, I did run into functions that had derivatives equal to 0 for which what I asked isn't true (like you showed in your example). But say we ban all those function from the $C^{\infty}$ class. Is it true then?

Comment: Add $e^x$ to the banned function. Now no derivatives are zero, but you have the same problem.